# Splash screen not opening first

Tags: android, splash-screen

Instead of opening the splash screen first, it opens the main activity then the splash screen.What might be  be the problem.The splash screen  wont go away until i press back button.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT=4000;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
     public void run(){
     Intent homeIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Splash.class);
     startActivity(homeIntent);
     finish();
     }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
   }
}
```

Comment: Add your Splash Activity as Launcher Activity in your android Manifest file.

Comment: Make splash activity as your default launcher activity in manifest file.

Comment: You are trying to open Splash from MainActivity. You need to define Splash as Launcher activity on AndroidManifest.
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>

Comment: it behaves exactly like your code is written. In your code splash launches only after main activity launched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AndroidManifest.xml,

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" />
```

And in the splashscreen.java onCreate function, you can set up a timer to call mainactivity

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            }
        },4000);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

**The best way to make a Splashscreen**

What you need :

- Two `Activity` : `MainActivity.java` and `SplashScreen.java`
- Two Layout : `layout_main_activity.xml` and `layout_splashscreen.xml`

In your AndroidManifest.xml, declare the two `Activity`. SplashScreen have to be the principal `Activity` (`MAIN` and `LAUNCHER`) :

```
        <!-- Splash screen -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.package.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Main activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.package.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

SplashScreen.java :

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, 3000); // for 3 seconds
    }

}
```

Comment: That was very helpfull

Comment: It's a pleasure to help :)